# Android NDK: Is it possible to switch APP_STL for multiple libraries?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a Application.mk and a Android.mk file.

Application.mk looks like

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

and my Android.mk looks like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := foo1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo1.cpp
# ... some other stuff ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := foo2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo2.cpp
# ... some other stuff ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now I want that library libfoo1 use c++_shared for APP_STL and libfoo2 use c++_static for APP_STL. (I know, normally that should not be made [relation between app_stl values with static and shared build android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854641/relation-between-app-stl-values-with-static-and-shared-build-android)). Is there a easy way without building a extra project and import the library to the other project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Do the following changes:

```
# Application.mk
APP_STL := none
```

This way you disable internal logic of choosing STL implementation of NDK build system. Now, specify manually which C++ stdlib implementation you want link with:

```
# Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := foo1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo1.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := c++_shared
# ... some other stuff ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := foo2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo2.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c++_static
# ... some other stuff ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cxx-stl/llvm-libc++)
```